# get and set analytic Log for button click using api

Tags: frontend, svelte

I am trying to store the button click logs user level so that I can use them  somewhere in my project can you help me and tell how I can do that thing user level and set them using an api and get them when ever needed I am using svelte for my front end (store the log using firebase or something similar).user level means for each user different data will be saved and and I can use userid to get the details for the user by using userid

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some decorator pattern applied to the event handler of interest.

Suppose you have a button and you want to log the `on:click` event. You can decorate the `handleClick` event handler with a decorator named `monitor`.

```html
<script>
import { getContext, onMount } from "svelte"

const monitor = getContext("monitor")

function handleClick(event) {
  // do stuff
}

</script>

<button on:click={monitor(handleClick)}>Click me</button>
```

Now in your root `<App />` component, you should initialize `monitor` decorator and set it into context.

```html
<script> // App.svelte
import { setContext } from "svelte"
import { Login } from "./components/Login.svelte"

let userId = null
const setUserId = (id) => { userId = id }

// the decorator wraps the original eventHandler
// and smuggles in some report logic
function monitor(eventHandler) {
  return function decoratedEventHandler() {
    // if we have the userId, we can start to report event logs
    if (userId) {
      const event = arguments[0]
      // impl report as you needed
      // it can simply be a HTTP POST to some backend API
      // I definitely suggest add some throttle mechanism into it
      report(userId, event) 
    }
    eventHandler.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}

setContext("monitor", monitor)

onMount(() => {
  // if you store userId in cookie,
  // you parse the cookie and restore it
  userId = getUserIdFromCookie(document.cookie)
})

</script>

<!-- 
or maybe your Login component has some special logic
to get userId from backend
-->

<Login updateUserId={setUserId} ></Login>
```

Comment: we can store the logs on firebase right and we can see them but can we do something that we can store them user level there and then access them from there any cloud service for this thing I want. I don't want to store the data in my database.